# Images not shown on IE11

Tags: image, http, http-headers, internet-explorer-11, placeholder

I'm using `Symfony2` and the `liip/imagine-bundle` however the images are not displayed on IE11 and just shows a `X` placeholder, other browsers are fine. Has anyone encountered this?

**UPDATE**

It seems that IE11 fails to get the content-type of a the image source. Basically I'm using an image source without the extension Ex. `<img src="/myimage" />` this is fine with other browsers however for IE11 it doesn't seem to recognise the file type.

Comment: Why the down vote? Please explain.

Comment: Not the down-voter, but you were probably down-voted because you did not include an MCVE, and your link does not work.

Comment: Thanks much appreciated @AlexanderO'Mara I find it unreasonable when someone down votes and does not explain why, doesn't help the community that much. Anyway, I've already modified the link and put some explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did was to remove the `no-sniff` directive

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  #Header set X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
</IfModule>
```

It seems that IE11 fails to get the correct content type of the image when `no-sniff` is turned on.

Comment: Well, it fails to recognize the type if you do not declare it, and do not allow it to sniff.

Comment: @JulianReschke yes but what is weird is that other browsers are fine. I needed that directive because of a requirement I need to fulfill. And I'm not sure why the original developer deliberately left the extension perhaps because the image was programmatically generated.

Comment: The explanation likely is that the other browsers do not understand the (non-standard) "X-Content-Type-Options" header field.